# File lost on pen drive

Tags: usb, file-recovery

I recently bought a pen drive to transfer data from my computer. I deleted a file on my computer because I thought all data had been transferred onto the stick.  But unfortunately, nothing was copied.  The problem is because I deleted this file at the same time I copied it. Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Did you check the recycle bin?

Answer (score 0):

If they are in Recycle Bin, then recover it....

Otherwise, use any recovery software package, like,

- Micro SD card recovery Pro(It can recover PC files also)
  Or any other.